# Handlebars sanitize string - SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, handlebars.js

I'm currently working on an app using [Publii CMS](https://getpublii.com/dev/)  which makes use of Handlebars. I'm creating a Vue app within the `positions.hbs` file. I'm retrieving a long string from the CMS using Handlebars to create a JSON object.

```
{{#getPostsByTags 30 "jobs" " "}}
  jobsData.push(
      {
        "title": "{{ title }}",
        "url": "{{ url }}",
        "mainTag": "{{ mainTag.name }}",
        "description": "{{ mainTag.description }}"
      }
    )
{{/getPostsByTags}}
```

The `{{ mainTag.description }}` grabs the text stored in the CMS and throws an error in the console.

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

I can see from the line 45 there might be new lines or characters that throws the error. On the line I can see the string to be as follow.

[image]

How can I sanitize or remove unwanted characters in Handlebars when passing it to the `description:` value? One thing I tried was to use JSON.stringify without success.

```
 "description": "JSON.stringify({{ mainTag.description }})"
```

[Learn More]

How can I go about sanitizing that string? or do I have to fix this from the CMS? I'm only storing text with `<p>` tags included. How can I go about solving this? I am then passing the data to the Vue app here is the full code.

```
<script>
    let jobsData = [];

    {{#getPostsByTags 30 "jobs" " "}}
      jobsData.push(
          {
            "title": "{{ title }}",
            "url": "{{ url }}",
            "mainTag": "{{ mainTag.name }}",
            "description": "{{ mainTag.description }}"
          }
        )
    {{/getPostsByTags}}

    window.onload = function () {
        var app = new Vue({
          delimiters: ['${', '}'],
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            jobs: jobsData
          },
          computed: {
            sectionTitlesWithJobs: function () {
              let tags = [];
              this.jobs.forEach(job=> {
                tags.push(job.mainTag)
              })

              tags = tags.filter((a, b) => tags.indexOf(a) === b)
              return tags.sort();
            }
          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

this is what the problematic string looks like:

```
"&lt;p&gt;The Product team conducts user research, creates user experience, and works closely with the internal and vendor technology teams to prototype, develop, and maintain evolving digital tools. The team also leads outreach, training and customer service for the &lt;/a href&#x3D;&quot;https://www1.nyc.gov/site/opportunity/portfolio/products.page&quot;&gt;products in its portfolio&lt;/a&gt;. The public-facing products include &lt;a href&#x3D;&quot;https://access.nyc.gov/&quot;&gt;ACCESS NYC&lt;/a&gt;,
        &lt;a href &quot;https://growingupnyc.cityofnewyork.us/&quot;&gt;Growing Up NYC&lt;/a&gt;, and &lt;a href&#x3D;&quot;https://growingupnyc.cityofnewyork.us/generationnyc/&quot;&gt;Generation NYC&lt;/a&gt; and their related APIs.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;The Product team works closely integrated with other NYC Opportunity teams, including the development, design, and data teams. It also engages with other program and technology staff across City government. The team helps NYC Opportunity and our agency partners translate anti-poverty program and policy goals into digital strategies. The team also helps define how the City of New York uses modern, agile and user-centric approach to technology products, including offering product management best practices. Working as part of the team is an opportunity to continue to build a model for in-house product development and serve as national leader in digital government innovation.&lt;/p&gt;"
```

Comment: It depends on the string. You've clipped the problematic part in your screenshot. Let's see the end of the line. Console.log the returned string.

Comment: @JoshWulf I updated the post with the string.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove new-line characters:

```
mainTag.description.split('\n').join('')
```

Comment: ```An error (1002) occurred during parsing index.hbs file.

Parse error on line 21:
...mainTag.description.split('\n').join('')
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'````

Comment: Updated it. Try that. That is the operation that you need to do to remove newlines.

Comment: `{{ description }}` wouldn't work since that is a handlebars delimeter and doesn't recognized what `description` is. I tried also  `${sinitizedDescription}` but that didn't work.

Comment: In that case, sanitize closer to the other boundary of your system. One boundary is the view layer, another is the data layer. Can you transform the data on load?